# Connecting to a specific IP address in C?

Tags: c, network-programming

I've done all my testing for my basic chat server and client by using this in the client code:

```
    struct sockaddr_in server;
  struct hostent * hp;

  server.sin_family = PF_INET;
  hp = gethostbyname( "localhost" );
  if ( hp == NULL )
  {
    perror( "Unknown host" );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

The emphasis is on the "localhost." This code has worked fine. Now I'm trying to test it between two computers, and I'm uncertain how to specify the name/address of the server I'd like to connect to. What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing need to be changed. Just replace `"localhost"` by `"192.168.0.1"` or `"stackoverflow.com"` and it should work.

Please note that `gethostbyname` if flagged as obsolete and should be replaced by `getaddrinfo`.

**Edit**

`getnameinfo` -> `getaddrinfo`

Comment: I find the arguments for getnameinfo very confusing, despite that I've been reading up on it since you posted this answer. Can you recommend any good explanations?

Comment: I think he meant `getaddrinfo`. getnameinfo is for reverse lookups (address => hostname)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you can pass any IP address into the `gethostbyname` function:

```
hp = gethostbyname( "74.125.224.73" );
```

or

```
    hp = gethostbyname( "google.com" );
```

Will get that IP address.